# What are some easy projects to start with?

Tags: camera-basics, project

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are good photography projects?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/978/what-are-good-photography-projects)

I am just starting to get into photography, and I know most of the basics of photography. I was just wondering what some easy projects are to get used to different settings. I use a lower end digital camera, and an old Sears KS-2. Neither is the best, but they are just for starters.

Is it better to take multiple pictures that are inside with similar lighting and things like that, or is it better to experiment with different settings and situations?

With the manual camera, I am always a little scared that the exposure won't be correct, so I need to get out and take more pictures, but I don't know where to start.

Any suggestions would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Whoops, I think you overlooked this question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/978/what-are-good-photography-projects, it is also about photography projects, many of these will give you more experience with your camera.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is a dupe of an existing question. It's a good one, but the answers there (plus the question itself) are loaded with ideas.

Comment: Welcome, Kristen. Sorry that your first question wasn't a match - we hope you'll stick around anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The best advice is, find something that you are interested in and can take a whole lot of pictures. Try different angles, situations, etc, but just take alot of pictures. The ideas listed in the above question, but the most important thing is, just take pictures, and lots of them.