# Do you have any ideas for a photo shoot that I can do at home with everyday things?

Tags: inspiration

I want to take pictures at home, but I can't think of things to shoot. Any ideas ?

Comment: Fundamentally related: "Where do you find the inspiration for your photographs?" http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7663/where-do-you-find-the-inspiration-for-your-photographs

Comment: And should probably be a CW as well.

Comment: @M.Walker : Totally agree, but I more specific to "at home".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Follow [@dailyshoot](https://twitter.com/#!/dailyshoot) on Twitter.  I did that for about a month, and having a daily 'assignment' was a great way to get me to take a picture every day (practice makes perfect, after all!) and to learn and try new things (would you believe, that's where I learned about DOF/bokeh?).

Comment: And be sure to check out the website: http://www.dailyshoot.com/

Comment: You may find you can get ideas from one of the "painting a day" blogs out there as well( http://www.google.com/search?q=painting+a+day ). Duane Keiser's site is probably the canonical example, but they all hinge on making compelling images of small everyday objects, food, etc. (Food shots, as I've said before, are hard to get right. You can probably learn more making food look delicious than from any other single genre of photography.)

Answer (score 5):

A common maxim for writers is "Write what you know." This applies to photography as well. Think of your interests, hobbies, job, or just plain daily experiences — at home or out and around — and find an element of that which has visual interest.

Comment: I like that. Shooting about what I know. I can be very interesting, I'm a computer engineer, code can be fun !

Comment: Absolutely. Although software is a little hard to capture visually (other than screen shots!) a lot of hardware is interesting to look at. Or from a larger point of view, if you don't mind mixing interests, consider what interesting computational things you can do with photography as an input. See for example http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5g8k-n4j_o

Answer (score 4):

A fun thing to do is try to catch anything falling into water.
Here is a lemon example, made by [@ysap](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1024/ysap), and [some tips](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7784/techniques-for-high-speed-photography) on how to create it.

In addition, shooting flames and fire is always a blast. If you don't have a fireplace use a candle.

[image]

Comment: You should probably give credit to @ysap for that photo and link to his answer directly. http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7784/techniques-for-high-speed-photography/7785#7785

Comment: the link is in the solution as markup to "some tips". it should redirect to the rfusca question and all the answers on how to get shots like this lemon.

Comment: Nevertheless, you give credit to @ysap for the photo.

Comment: Wow, that's surprising... for a minute I was not sure if I already answered this question... Given all the recent questions regarding copyright etc., I wonder what is the proper way to act here. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ysap - Sue? ;) lol

Comment: Regardless of legal implications or whatnot, I personally think its inappropriate to use another member's image in an answer without their permission.  As a courtesy if nothing else.

Comment: @rfusca - LOL indeed. For the spirit of the forum and the discussion, I'll take this as a compliment, assuming no harm was intended. However, I'd appreciate a nicer attribution, something like "Here is a lemon example, made by @ysap, and some tips on how to create it.". The current attribution is kind of lost in the frame.

Comment: @ysap, I always embed my copyright info into the image, and into its metadata. If someone posts it, and that info is gone, it is a malicious attempt to defeat the copyright notice, which is a bad thing; I've been there and dealt with it and it's not fun. I'd say someone owes you a deep and heartfelt apology.

Comment: @Greg — it's not necessarily true that removal of EXIF data indicates malicious intent. Many file upload sites strip EXIF (to save a few bytes of storage and data transfer, I guess?). And, imgur.com, the site used by Stack Exchange for uploaded images, is one of them. (Flickr is another notable example.)

Comment: I didn't say EXIF data. I said metadata, but should have clarified it as the IPTC data. And, if both the copyright notice in the IPTC metadata and a copyright notice inside the image are stripped, it is intentional; My IP lawyer really liked it when I pointed out both had been stripped in a copyright infringement case I had. In particular, the visual copyright mark and notice carries a lot of weight in such cases.

Comment: @Greg - what is IPTC?

Comment: [IPTC](http://www.iptc.org/site/Home/) is an international standard for tagging and describing images for use by news media. Wikipedia has a [quick overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPTC) of it. Apps like Adobe's Lightroom and Photoshop, Apple's Aperture and Camera Bit's PhotoMechanic make it easy to add/edit the information, which is either stored inside the file, or in a sidecar file, then used by an agency to pull out the particulars of the image, such as when and where an image was taken and by whom, along with the copyright info.

Answer (score 4):

There's [a Flickr group called "Household Objects"](http://www.flickr.com/groups/householdobjects/pool/) that might offer you some inspiration.

You could also try searching Flickr for the names of household objects you have on hand: [pencils](http://www.flickr.com/search/?q=pencils&w=all), [bottles](http://www.flickr.com/search/?ss=2&w=all&q=bottles&m=text), [crayons](http://www.flickr.com/search/?ss=2&w=all&q=crayons&m=text), [thread](http://www.flickr.com/search/?ss=2&w=all&q=thread&m=text), [tools](http://www.flickr.com/search/?ss=2&w=all&q=tools&m=text), etc.

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm... Around the home and everyday things assuming that 'incense' is an everyday thing around your house... Shoot smoke pictures.

[image]

No two are every the same, and there are about a thousand interesting ways you can post process 'em to add interest...

Answer (score 3):

When practicing particular techniques, I often take pictures literally of whatever is in front of me at the time. So, for instance, when playing with depth of field, I'll shoot my water bottle on my desk so that I can see the blur in the plants in the background.

Technically, it's a perfect photo. Aesthetically it's boring, so I never show it to anyone. I'll usually delete it and move on.

If you want something to show people, then you start the same place you'd start with any other photograph: *what is your intent by making this picture*? What story are you trying to tell? What effect on the user are you trying to achieve?

In your house, there's plenty of subject matter for this, just as there is outside of it. Any person can become a portrait; any object can become a still life.

And any pet can get a [capshun and posted to the Internet](http://icanhascheezburger.com/). :-)

Comment: I like the concept of "Story". I think that is what I looking for. A good story. A bit like Still-motion of legos or stuff like that. Thanks for the point !

Answer (score 2):

A little inspiration from me: :-)

[image: Cupstack]

Comment: Sweet colors ! It's daylight right ?

Comment: Daylight + post-processing :-)

Answer (score 1):

My wife likes to do macros and light-paintings of flower bouquets. It's amazing what she can do with an ironing board with a black drop-cloth in a bathroom that has no windows plus a high-grade white LED flashlight and some colored gels or cellophane and a camera on a tripod.

Also look into the [Lens Baby](http://www.lensbaby.com/) lenses. They're a fun, primitive, not-too-expensive tilt-shift lens that gives a different view to anything you shoot with them.

Answer (score -5):

Anything and everything if you have the eye

Comment: This and nothing.. I mean, I searching ideas, no comment about the fact that I don't have ideas. This does help me.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and in fact, does little more than [beg the question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question).