# What are good/memorable Photography Society topics or events?

Tags: teaching, clubs

I'm a member of the QUB PhotoSoc and trying to plan next years agenda. Unfortunately few of our exec have attend other photography societies and with the society being quite young we are stuck with ideas for possible topics for meetings. We are all learners, exec included.

Can anyone suggest any good topics of photography events, perhaps events you've attended that were particularly memorable?

Some ideas we have include:

- Disposable Camera challenge - remove the safety blanket of being able to see your photos for a fun challenge
- Pub Crawl Photo Hunt - the society travel on a pub crawl while each person/team have to complete a set of photo related challenges (good for fun, not for skills)
- Mock Formal - we use this to train people how to use the lighting kits we own correctly. Everyone comes to the meeting in full formal gear. A good laugh and some real skills learnt.

Comment: Related: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/978/what-are-good-photography-projects

Comment: Bit of a language question here: What is QUB?  And is a Photography Society similar to what would probably be called a Camera Club here in the US?

Comment: Queen's University of Belfast?

Answer (score 5):

Your current ideas are great! Here's a few ideas for photo meetups. I assume you're able to meet during the day on weekends as well as for evening sessions:

- Photo walks: find a few interesting areas of the city or countryside near you, and arrange a rough route (finishing at a pub). Everyone takes lots of photos and hopefully learn techniques from each other, and enjoy exploring a new area
- Treasure hunt: make a list of 5 items / concepts / actions and group members into teams. Each team has to create a photo of each of the five things; the popular vote is used to decide which team "won". Finish the hunt at a pub!
- Off-camera flash: find someone with some flash guns and remote triggers (or buy some cheap ones for the club); take turns experimenting with different lighting angles, diffusers, reflectors, snoods, gels and so forth, followed by some beer
- Shortest night / day: take all night or all day to take photos on the shortest day and night of the year, stopping off in a few bars if necessary
- Presentations - if you have a few experienced members (or you can get hold of some other experienced photographers) try getting them to do a presentation on some of these topics, with the promise of free drinks

  - Photography for newbies (what is aperture / shutter speed / ISO, etc)
  - Macro
  - Garden photography
  - Studio lighting
  - Stock photography
  - Wedding photography
  - Astrophotography
  - Composition
  - Wildlife photography
  - Post-processing using Photoshop / Aperture / Lightroom
- Drinks - get together in a pub for a chat!

Comment: A good list. I'd add 'Photographing photographers' - when you're out on one of these activities, half (or some arbitrary proportion) spend half an hour or so only taking photos of the others taking photos (if that makes sense). Swap afterwards.