# Beginner's guide

Tags: dslr, books, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the first few photography books someone should read?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16/whats-the-first-few-photography-books-someone-should-read)

Hi,

Inspired by [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/164/what-are-your-easiest-beginner-tips), Is there a good online tutorial or book about the basics of photography?

Most of the sources I've read include detailed lens specs, camera-specific data or the history of cameras from the [Camera Obscura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_obscura) onwards and recommendations for highly priced gadgets I am not going to buy. Unfortunately, I have simple Point-And-Shoot, and a friend's DSLR once in a while.

I'm interested with short and practical explanation about focus, exposure, depth of field, light and flash, composition and common pitfalls.

Thanks,

Adam