# What resources can help a new photographer with terminology and concepts?

Tags: digital, camera-basics, tips, learning

Dad has been a professional photographer, so photography comes in the heredity.
although I live far away from him so i can't be taught by him.
I enjoy photography and want to start with serious photography.
Any links, pointers, tutorials to something that helps building the essential concept which will further help me understand the terminology photographers use, will be very helpful.

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/164/21

Comment: :-)  Thanks for the warm welcome! and Thanks for the Edit! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the best sites for a beginning photographers (as well as pros) is [Cambridge in Color](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials.htm). This excellent site has some superb writers, and their articles are clear, concise, and thoroughly demonstrate their points with sample images, figures, and some basic math. You can learn a lot there.

Another great beginner site (and even for those who are decently skilled photographers) is [Digital Photography School](http://www.digital-photography-school.com/). This is a great site that is chock full of tutorials, tips and tricks, articles, and more. You can find an article for just about anything related to digital photography there, from choosing cameras, to learning about exposure and camera settings, to composition, to post processing techniques.

There are also numerous other sites on the net for beginners and experts alike. If you like the nitty gritty low level theory about everything photography, another excellent site is the [Luminous Landscape](http://www.luminous-landscape.com/index.shtml). The articles here are often fairly old and pertain to film, but the underlying theory is sound, and most of it still applies to digital photography today. Be ware, while this site has some fantastic articles regarding composition, exposure, etc, it also contains many heavy duty articles that discuss the low level theory of optics, film, sensors, light, etc. If you like mathematics, its a wonderful site. If you hate math, you can avoid the gritty articles and stick to the ones that discuss practical things like composition.

Answer (score 2):

Once you get your feet wet, I'm personally finding [Scott Kelby's Digital Photography Volumes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321678737) very helpful.  They don't cover the technical lingo, so you'd need that first and to get out there with your camera a bit first, but after a short time I'm finding it a great resource.  He's got a great writing style and its an easy read.

I'm a newbie to photography as well, but nothing seems to help quite as much as just getting out there with your camera first.

Comment: That will be exactly what I was expecting. I do get out with the camera and do the stuff on my own, but whenever I need some remarkable shots and i want to learn things online, I just don't get the lingo and the methods' they suggest. so getting terminology and photo-sense correctly would be a great help!!

Comment: Ooo.. that's having a high price!! I live in India and though it would be an online tutorial.. free kinda thing :-P . Its around 2000 bucks in my country. okay, I'll buy it sometime

Answer (score 1):

dpreview is a nice resource for anything DSLR-related, and has some good guides:
http://www.dpreview.com/learn/

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of books covering photography basics such as Michael Langford's "Starting Photography". Try it out.

But in my opinion the best way to learn is:

1. Make 10 images
2. Look at 1000 images
3. Make 100 images
4. Look at 10.000 images
   ...
   ;-)

Answer (score 0):

ephotozine also is a good resource for anything photography:

http://www.ephotozine.com

Lots to read and do there.